# Using .runsettings to exclude assemblies from code coverage

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, code-coverage, vs-unit-testing-framework

When running code coverage for my solution which contains multiple projects, I noticed that Code Coverage includes also my test assemblies.

I found an article which suggests the following template for .runsettings:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
        <Configuration>
          <CodeCoverage>
            <ModulePaths>
              <Include>
                <!-- Do not specify any includes. This will attempt to include all binaries -->
              </Include>
              <Exclude>
                <!-- Exclude modules that aren't to be processed, by their name / path -->
                <ModulePath>.*Tests\.dll$</ModulePath> <!-- I put it here -->
              </Exclude>
            </ModulePaths>

            <UseVerifiableInstrumentation>True</UseVerifiableInstrumentation>
            <AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>True</AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>
            <CollectFromChildProcesses>True</CollectFromChildProcesses>
            <CollectAspDotNet>False</CollectAspDotNet>
            <!--
Additional paths to search for symbol files. Symbols must be found for modules to be instrumented.
If symbols are alongside the binaries, they are automatically picked up. Otherwise specify the here.
Note that searching for symbols increases code coverage runtime. So keep this small and local.

<SymbolSearchPaths>             
  <Path>C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 11\Projects\ProjectX\bin\Debug</Path>
  <Path>\\mybuildshare\builds\ProjectX</Path>
</SymbolSearchPaths>
-->
            <Functions>
              <Exclude>
                <Function>^std::.*</Function>
                <Function>^ATL::.*</Function>
                <Function>.*::__GetTestMethodInfo.*</Function>
                <Function>^Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppCodeCoverageFramework::.*</Function>
                <Function>^Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::.*</Function>
                <Function>.*::YOU_CAN_ONLY_DESIGNATE_ONE_.*</Function>
              </Exclude>
            </Functions>
            <Attributes>
              <Exclude>
                <Attribute>^System.Diagnostics.DebuggerHiddenAttribute$</Attribute>
                <Attribute>^System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute$</Attribute>
                <Attribute>^System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute$</Attribute>
                <Attribute>^System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute$</Attribute>
                <Attribute>^System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute$</Attribute>
              </Exclude>
            </Attributes>
            <Sources>
              <Exclude>
                <Source>.*\\atlmfc\\.*</Source>
                <Source>.*\\vctools\\.*</Source>
                <Source>.*\\public\\sdk\\.*</Source>
                <Source>.*\\microsoft sdks\\.*</Source>
                <Source>.*\\vc\\include\\.*</Source>
              </Exclude>
            </Sources>
            <CompanyNames>
              <Exclude>
                <CompanyName>.*microsoft.*</CompanyName>
              </Exclude>
            </CompanyNames>
            <PublicKeyTokens>
              <Exclude>
                <PublicKeyToken>^B77A5C561934E089$</PublicKeyToken>
                <PublicKeyToken>^B03F5F7F11D50A3A$</PublicKeyToken>
                <PublicKeyToken>^31BF3856AD364E35$</PublicKeyToken>
                <PublicKeyToken>^89845DCD8080CC91$</PublicKeyToken>
                <PublicKeyToken>^71E9BCE111E9429C$</PublicKeyToken>
                <PublicKeyToken>^8F50407C4E9E73B6$</PublicKeyToken>
                <PublicKeyToken>^E361AF139669C375$</PublicKeyToken>
              </Exclude>
            </PublicKeyTokens>
          </CodeCoverage>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

Now the problem is that as soon as I check my .runsettings file in the TEST\Test settings menu, I see Code Coverage analyzes only one of many assemblies in my solution.

Even if I remove the line

```
 <ModulePath>.*Tests\.dll$</ModulePath> <!-- I put it here -->
```

only one assembly is analyzed. I would like to avoid adding all my assemblies to the Include list, I  just need to exclude all the test assemblies.

**Why does .runsettings make code coverage see only one of the assemblies in my VS solution?**

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/jj635153.aspx says that you can remove every entry in this file (as default values are used). Try to start with an empty file and add one region after the other.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue, with a much simpler file. With the default runsettings file, I'm able to get code coverage. When I tried to exclude a third party library (for example), then running the Code Coverage analysis results in ... nothing. No errors, no warnings, just nothing. Comment that exclusion out, and everything works again.

Comment: simply adding the english (en-us) version of the MSDN link supplied by @habakuk  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj635153.aspx

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[The issue is the period](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16616574/1045767). For some reason the RegEx is choking on that. You can get around it by escaping the period as follows:

```
<ModulePaths>
    <Include>
        <ModulePath>.*MyCompany\.Namespace\.Project\.dll$</ModulePath>
    </Include>
    <Exclude>
        <ModulePath>.*ThirdParty\.Namespace\.Project\.dll$</ModulePath>
    </Exclude>
</ModulePaths>
```

Also, the empty includes are valid and imply that all Modules are included. The comments of the Microsoft provided sample state that:

```
<!--
About include/exclude lists:
Empty "Include" clauses imply all; empty "Exclude" clauses imply none.
Each element in the list is a regular expression (ECMAScript syntax).
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/2k3te2cs.aspx.
An item must first match at least one entry in the include list to be included.
Included items must then not match any entries in the exclude list to remain included.
-->
```

Comment: I have 2 projects with one solution. I need exclude test project assembly ?how to do this

Answer (score 15):

On a related note,  I ran into this post because I was bit thinking clearly about the regular expression nature of the include and exclude paths. For my WPF application, I wanted to exclude coverage analysis on Caliburn.Micro. So I had written

```
<ModulePath>Caliburn.Micro.dll</ModulePath>
```

Clearly, the period is messing me up. This question does not suffer from that problem, but I bet I’m not the only one to overlook this simple fact. For any other readers, please also take note that * is not a wildcard – it is the regular expression “any number of” operator. You do not want `*.Caliburn`, but rather `.*Caliburn` Thus this simple statement solved my problem:

```
<ModulePath>.*Caliburn.*</ModulePath>
```

Because it is looking for a path, not just a module name, you need the .* in front of the module to ignore it – that is, you want to ignore it at any given file path.

Comment: Your solution is the correct one. It is not a simple wildcard or regex but is a Path so the .* is kind of mandatory otherwise you should know the full path of the .dll which is impossible of TFS Azure.

Answer (score 14):

As I couldn't find this answer anywhere else, and this just took me a while to figure out, `ModulePath` is the full path, and you may be matching your pattern somewhere else in the path.

For example, if you have a project `Foo` and a project `Foo.Tests`, and they are built to their own directories, you will end up with `Foo.Tests\bin\Release\Foo.dll` and `Foo.Tests\bin\Release\Foo.Tests.dll`. This is the dll that the test assembly will reference, so this is the path that is used. `Foo\bin\Release\Foo.dll` is not directly referenced by the test assembly.

If you try to exclude `.*tests.*` it will match both paths and produce no coverage.

To only exclude assemblies with "test" in their file name, ignoring their path, I used

```
<Exclude>
  <ModulePath>.*\\[^\\]*test[^\\]*\.dll</ModulePath>
</Exclude>
```

Comment: "If you try to exclude .*tests.* it will match both paths and produce no coverage." It had exactly this problem. Your answer saved my time.

Comment: Thank you, this needs to get way more votes. A lot of these answers completely miss the "full path" aspect, focusing on the troublesome dot or name matching, when the folder path might just as well contain parts of your namespace.

Comment: Thank you! I've been fumbling all day until now that I read your post. I knew immediately this was the reason my runsettings was excluding all my code! Thank you!!!

Comment: Will this exclude references to third party libraries too like fluent validation etc?

Answer (score 2):

I had all sorts of issues getting `<ModulePaths>` to work reliably (using ASP.NET Core 2.1).

In the end I found that using the `<Sources>` was simple and more reliable and worked exactly as I needed.  You still leverage the advice on the use of regex.

I include my solution path, and exclude my \tests subfolders where all my test projects live. Example for CodeCoverage element in RunSettings xml file:

```
<CodeCoverage>
  <Sources>
    <Include>
      <Source>.*\\My\.Solution\.Name\.Space\\.*</Source> <!-- ie: include *\My.Solution.Name.Space\* -->
    </Include>
    <Exclude>
      <Source>.*\\My\.Solution\.Name\.Space\\Tests\\.*</Source> <!-- ie: exclude *\My.Solution.Name.Space\Tests\* -->
    </Exclude>
  </Sources>
  <!-- removed for brevity -->
<CodeCoverage>
```

See more at: [Customising Code Coverage on MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/customizing-code-coverage-analysis?view=vs-2017)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I couldn't get the other answers working for me, but I got this working, as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159530.aspx:

```
<ModulePath>.*\\MyProject\.Test\.dll$</ModulePath>
```